# Find deviation in grid walk

Tags: combinatorics

I have a problem where one can walk on a rectangular grid of dimensions $m \times n$ and origin $(0,0)$. You can only walk up or right.
Though the problem of how many path there are is fairly simple ([reference](https://brilliant.org/wiki/rectangular-grid-walk-no-restriction/)),

I need to find the deviation of any path from the straight path. The deviation of a path is defined as: $$\max\left(\frac{x}{m} - \frac{y}{n}, \frac{y}{n} - \frac{x}{m}\right)$$

What should I consider the straight path? Is it the diagonal line between $(0,0)$ and $(m,n)$?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2758233/418145

Comment: Is the deviation of a path the maximum of the deviations calculated at each grid point of the path?

Comment: Since you have a formula for calculating the deviation, knowing what is meant by the "straight path" is actually not relevant. However, since a straight line from $(0,0)$ to $(m,n)$ would give a deviation of $0$ at any point on the line, it is a good bet that this is what the authors of the deviation formula considered the "straight path".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "straight line" distance between the two points is know as the **Euclidean distance**, and is indeed calculated by $$\sqrt{\left(m-0\right)^2+\left(n-0\right)^2}$$

Now, the formula you've provided is the [**Chebyshev distance**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance), but what you're actually looking for, since you can only go up or right, is the [**Manhattan distance**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance). The [difference](https://lyfat.wordpress.com/2012/05/22/euclidean-vs-chebyshev-vs-manhattan-distance/) is subtle, but it makes a difference.

The manhattan distance is calculated using the formula $$\mid{m-0}\mid+\mid{n-0}\mid$$

Hope that helps!

Comment: That is more clear, thanks. The issue I'm trying to solve is calculating the average deviation of all paths between (0,0) and any point (m,n) on the grid.

Comment: @BrunoCortez The deviation from point $p$ on the Manhattan path and point $p$ on the Euclidean path would be $\sqrt{\left( e_x - m_x \right)^2+\left(e_y - m_y \right)^2}$. Where $e_x$ is the x-coordinate of the Euclidean path at point $p$ and $m_x$ is the x-coordinate of the Manhattan path at point $p$. So the average deviation would just be the average of all these values for a given Manhattan path and the Euclidean path